# Initialize variables in a class method?

Tags: c++, class, variables, initialization

I have a silly question:

I have a class and in one of its methods I have to do some calculations and I need to declare some variables that are useful to do this. For example:

```
class Percettrone {
public:
    Percettrone(double NL);
    void fit(double X, double y);
}
.
.
.
void Percettrone::fit(double X, double y)
{
        double delta[50][50];
        double conteggio=0;
        //calculations
}
```

Is it correct? Or is it better to declare when I create the class? Moreover I have to call this method lots of time during my programme

Comment: It is viable solution. Unless you have performance problem and identify that it is creation/initialization of local variables, no need to move them as member data.

Comment: If the variables are job specific and are not going to be used in another method of this class, then it is correct to use them as locals, although, if there is some repetitiveness, I'd suggest you make them members.

Comment: Im a lazy programmer who works alone and I cant be bothered doing .h files unless I need to so I usually declare it within the class rather than outside of it. The way youve did the class definition, stating only definitions and not asserting any values means that the class can be contained in a separate .h file with the methods declared there contained in your .cpp file. The separation makes the code more readable but it can be overkill if you ask me.

Comment: If the variables are needed in `Percettrone::fit` then that is the correct place to declare them. Why would you want to put them somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

If those variables are affecting the object instance and identifying its state, then you must declare them in the class as attributes. On the other hand, if they're just helper variables in the function, and you don't need to use them anywhere else, then make them local inside the function as you did in the example.